# Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'sdoh_category_id' cannot be null

Tags: laravel

it says that my column cannot be null but when I dump my data, it's not null.
I want to store the the data from the dropdown to the database it says the column is null.

controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $household = new HouseholdHead;

    $household->name = $request->name;
    $household->purok_id = $request->purok;
    $household->env_hazard_id = $request->hazards;
    $household->number_of_adults = $request->adults;

    $household->save();

    $categories = ['religion', 'residence', 'type', 'toilet', 'water_source','garbage', 'alcohol','dental', 'h_service', 'm_service', 'routine', 'exposure', 'reasons', 'insurance', 'info', 'w_hazards', 'c_hazards', 'unmet', 'improve', 'screening' ];

    
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $sdohCategory = new SDOHCategoryHousehold();
        $sdohCategory->household_head_id = $household->id;
        $sdohCategory->sdoh_category_id = $request->get($category);
        $sdohCategory->save();
    }



    return redirect()->route('admin.household.index')->with('success', 'Household Added Successfully!');
}
```

dump data:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your array has "m_service" but your request has "m_service_id=" because of that not found but it try to save and your column not null

Answer (score 0):

If you fill some field of the method and it's null when inserting into DB, probably you need to add that into YourModel::$fillable array